# How share some f:event of f:metadata between selected XHTML with managed bean interface as parameter

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, jsf-2.3

Noting that from [JSF view metadata demystified](http://www.omnifaces-fans.org/2015/11/jsf-view-metadata-facet-demystified.html):

> Since this tag is about current view metadata it doesn't participate
>   in XHTML templates (the page author must ensure that the 
>   element does not appear on a template or included page; it can be in a
>   template client) and it is direct child of `<f:view>`.

I have multiple `<f:viewParam>` and `<f:event>` that repeat in many XHTML pages, which are in turn clients of a `template.xhtml`. Each `f:event` depends on a given managed bean, where the managed bean is different for each XHTML page (but respects a common interface, i.e., the same operations for the listeners exist for every relevant managed bean):

```
<f:view>
    <f:metadata>

        <!-- I want to share this across many XHTML parametrised by the bean -->
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{particularBean.id}"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{particularBean.opCommon1}"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{particularBean.opCommon2}"/>
        <!-- END SHARED PORTION -->

        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{particularBean.onlyForMe}"/>

    </f:metadata>
</f:view>

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
```

Q: How can I encapsulate the shared `<f:viewParam>` and `<f:event>` portion so that it can be "included" and treated as a common policy fragment, with particular managed beans (meeting the common interface) passed in for each XHTML page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in one of my own older projects (as I posted I recalled vaguely I had investigated this already at some stage years ago). This works:

In `/include/shared.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
 >
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{particularBean.id}"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{compatibleBean.opCommon1}"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{compatibleBean.opCommon2}"/>
</ui:composition>
```

And in any client:

```
<f:view>
 <f:metadata>

  <ui:include src="/included/shared.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="compatibleBean" value="#{particularBean}"/>
  </ui:include>

  <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{particularBean.onlyForMe}"/>

 </f:metadata>
</f:view>
```